# Attribute back to default value on checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, products, ce-1.9.2.0

Please help. The configurable price is £39 and over a certain size it is £42, but when you add say a size 9 to basket, in the cart it defaults back to size 2.

I have the 'Simple configurable product' module, but when a customer clicks a different size, on the checkout page it goes back to default size

Comment: This extension / these types of extensions are notoriously flaky and impossible to support here.